# How to return a response from axios in Vue

Tags: vue.js, axios

I read all answered questions on stack overflow but still unable to figure out how to make this work.

**File1.js**

I send some data to server using axios ajax call as follows:

```
function ajaxSearchAxios(searchType,searchText){ 
    var searchResults=[];
    axios({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'ajaxSearch/',
        data: {
              searchType: searchType,
              searchText: searchText,
            },
        responseType: 'json',
      })
      .then ( function (response){
          searchResults = response.data['searchResults']; console.log('JS searchResults=',searchResults[0].value) //this prints nicely to the console
          return searchResults

      })
      .catch ( function (error){
        console.log('ajaxSearch error'); 
      });
}
```

**File2.js**

Here I have my Vue code where I want to take output of `ajaxSearchAxios()` and store in Vue data.

```
new Vue({
    el:'#id_1',
    data:{
            SearchResults:[],
    },
    methods:{
        ajaxSearch:function(searchType){
            this.SearchResults= ajaxSearchAxios('s','s1');
            console.log('VUE =',this.SearchResults[0].value)
        },
    },
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 12):

Remember, you're dealing with asynchronous functions, so your function needs to return and handle the functionality as a `Promise`

```js
function ajaxSearchAxios(searchType,searchText){ 
    return axios({ // <--- return the PROMISE
        method: 'post',
        url: 'ajaxSearch/',
        data: {
              searchType: searchType,
              searchText: searchText,
            },
        responseType: 'json',
      })
      .then ( function (response){
          return response.data['searchResults']; 
      })
      .catch ( function (error){
        console.log('ajaxSearch error'); 
      });
}
```

and then handle it as a promise, instead of assigning the function to value

```js
new Vue({
    el:'#id_1',
    data:{
            SearchResults:[],
    },
    methods:{
        ajaxSearch:(searchType) => {
            // execute axios promise and on success, assign result to var
            ajaxSearchAxios('s','s1').then(result => this.SearchResults = result)
        },
    },
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain whats happening in ajaxSearchAxios('s','s1').then(result => this.SearchResults = result).  Is result = the data returned by .then() function in ajaxSearchAxios

Comment: What that does is the equivalent of inserting itself as another `then` call between `then` and `catch` of the axios Promise. when you return the axios promise in the `ajaxSearchAxios` function, you can chain further promises to it.

Answer (score 3):

**Asynchronous calls from axios in Vue:**

```
var v1 = new Vue({
    el: '#id_mainPage',
    data: {
        branches: [''],
    },
    methods: {
        ajaxAxiosGetFunc: async function (url) {
            var output = '';
            await axios({
                method: 'get',
                url: url,
                data: {},
                responseType: 'json',
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    output = response.data;
                }.bind(this))
                .catch(function (error) {
                    console.log('ajax get branches error');
                });
            return output
        },

        getAllBranchNames: async  function(){
            var output = await this.ajaxAxiosGetFunc('http://localhost:9977/get_branches');  // called asynchronously to wait till we get response back
            this.branches = output['branches'];
        },
    },
    mounted: function () {
        console.log('Vue mounted');
        this.getAllBranchNames();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please detail why your answer is a good solution. Help those who stumble upon your answer understand what the code does. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

I assume calling `ajaxSearchAxios` is working and you've imported file1 correctly. If so, Axios returns a promise, so try returning the axios obj and using `async` and `await` in vue to wait for the result like this...

```js
function ajaxSearchAxios(searchType,searchText){ 
    var searchResults=[];
    return axios({
        method: 'post',
...
```

```js
new Vue({
    el:'#id_1',
    data:{
            SearchResults:[],
    },
    methods:{
        ajaxSearch: async searchType => {
            this.SearchResults = await ajaxSearchAxios('s','s1');
            console.log('VUE =',this.SearchResults[0].value)
        },
    },
});
```